# Writing an excel workbook to a memoryStream

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, memorystream

I would like save an newly created Excel in a MemoryStream. Here my code:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
...

public void Create(){
  Excel.Application xlApp;
  Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
  Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

  //Complete xlWorkSheet

  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  xlWorkBook.SaveAs(ms);

  xlWorkBook.Close(false, misValue, misValue);
  xlApp.Quit();
}
```

The problem is when I breakpoint just after **xlWorkBook.SaveAs(ms)**, ms is empty (the length is 0). Moreover, when saving, a file "System.IO.MemoryStream" is created on the PC (in the folder *Documents*). Plus, I tried **ExportAsFixedFormat** and it worked well (but the document is saved on the PC).
Then, **SaveToStream** doesn't exist here.

I am developing an application Web ASP.NET MVC4 in Visual Studio 2012 and Dotnet 4.5. The language is C#.
It is possible to save a workBook in a memoryStream without saving it on the PC?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

have you tried following option?

```
xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Copy(Type.Missing);
```

Comment: Hello Nil23, I tried the option you proposed. 
  Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
  //Complete xlWorkSheet
  xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Copy(Type.Missing);
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  xlWorkBook.SaveAs(ms);     
    
  It still doesn't work...

Comment: I noticed something : I think **xlWorkBook.SaveAs(ms)** can be used only if **xlWorkBook = new XLWorkbook()** (from ClosedXML)...ClosedXML is available in Visual Studio 2012? If yes, what library?

Answer (score 0):

**Processor is Running in background**
you have tried
Try this to terminate the process "Excel.exe"

```
'foreach (Process proc in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Excel"))
           {
           proc.Kill();
           }'
```